# required=true page parameter not working?

Tags: seam

I've just discovered a required attribute in the pages.xml:

```
<page view-id="/competition-list.xhtml">
  <param name="season" value="#{seasonHome.id}" converterId="javax.faces.Integer" validator="#{startYearValidator}" required="true" />
</page>
```

However, when manually deleting the parameter from the URL nothing happens, that is the query is still executed (though it returns no elements), which I didn't expect.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Page parameter validation affects the execution of page action. When validation fails, page action is not executed and a `FacesMessage` is added.

Maybe you want to add a page action to load competitions so that the query is not executed when the `season` parameter is not valid:

```
<page view-id="/competition-list.xhtml"
      action="#{seasonHome.loadCompetitions}">
  <param name="season"
         value="#{seasonHome.id}"
         converterId="javax.faces.Integer"
         validator="#{startYearValidator}"
         required="true" />
</page>
```